# Function with "break" inside

Tags: python, integer, break

I am currently working on a small project for a master's course.

I would like to make a short game, and I am using very often the same question.

I would like to make functions, but to ask the user the choice he wants to make (integer) I should make the following codes:

```
def IntNumber(fac):
    while True :
        num_fac = int(input("How many %s do you want to buy?" %fac))
        try:
            num_fac = int(input("How many %s do you want to buy?" %fac))
            if num_fac <0 :
                raise ValueError(num_fac, "is not valid.")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not a valid number!")
            continue
```

However, with a "break" inside I can't make the function work the way I want: the value of num_fac is deleted, and I get an error message that num_fac isn't defined.

How can I do that otherwise? I really need to make my codes shorter and more efficient!

Comment: What do you mean by *"with a "break" inside I can't make the function work."*? What is the error message?

Comment: it doesnt work is not really helpful? what doesnt work about it?

Comment: @hey-lo--rather than `break` why don't you have `return num_fac` (otherwise how is the caller getting the value).  Also, why do you have `num_fac = ...` twice?  It seems you only need the one inside the try/except block.

Comment: the "break" cancel the num_fac and doesn't permit to use it later!

Comment: and if i only write num_fac once, i get an error message that num_fac isn't define!

Comment: looks like `num_fac` is a local variable. You might need to return it, for example

Comment: yes i think it is a local variable, but I don't know how to make it otherwise